# How to write sumproduct formulas in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook with a lot of sheets and there is one sheet that I would like to be calculated only when pushing a button. This sheet is very small and contains only 10 formulas: please see the picture below.

[image]

Many of these formulas are sumproduct :

Formula 1 `=SUMPRODUCT('Loan Overview'!$S$2:$S$55,'Loan Overview'!$AE$2:$AE$55*('Loan Overview'!$L$2:$L$55=TRUE))/SUMIF('Loan Overview'!$L:$L,TRUE,'Loan Overview'!$S:$S)`

Formula 2 `=SUMPRODUCT('Loan Overview'!$S$1:$S$500,'Loan Overview'!$T$1:$T$500)`

Formula 3 `=SUMIFS('Loan Overview'!$AJ$1:$AJ$500,'Loan Overview'!$L$1:$L$500,TRUE)/(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN('Loan Overview'!$B$1:$B$500)>0))-(1+COUNTIF('Loan Overview'!$AJ$1:$AJ$500,"N/A")))`

I wanted to know if there is an easy way to convert excel formulas into VBAs and then assign them to a button.

Comment: Hoping to understand what it is you are trying, I don't think moving these formulas to VBA is what you want. Keep them in your sheet, change calculation to manual and make buttons that will only calculate the cells of interest.

Comment: Hye, thank you guys for your help, I have found a workaround but I still have one "end of statement error" with one my sub :

Comment: Sub Average_Credit_Score()
Set slWks = Sheets("Reporting")
Range("B4").Formula = "=SUMIFS('Loan Overview'!$AJ$1:$AJ$500,'Loan Overview'!$L$1:$L$500,TRUE)/(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN('Loan Overview'!$B$1:$B$500)>0))-(1+COUNTIF('Loan Overview'!$AJ$1:$AJ$500,"N/A")))"
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You can use several Excel function as a VBA function.

This is explained in [this URL about Application.Worksheetfunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.worksheetfunction).

So, the functions you're looking for, can be used as `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct()`, `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs()`, ...